# Script to backup folders

Tags: bash, backup

I have a folder in `/opt/backup` in which folders are created every day. In order to save space I would like to [gunzip](/questions/tagged/gunzip) all folders that are older than 2 days.

I don't want to create one single zip file but rather zip each folder on its own, with the name preserved. I have tried:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Backup files

files=($(find /opt/backup/ -mtime +"2"))
for files in ${files[*]}
do
    echo $files
    tar cvfz backup.tar.gz $files
done
```

But all this does is creating a single zip file, I would like each folder separately.

The script will run every 2 days at 02:00 in the morning. How do I write this script, please?

Answer (score 1):

You are making it too complicated. You should [find](/questions/tagged/find) directories that are old enough and simply tar zip those.

```
find /opt/backup/ -mtime +"2" -type d -exec tar cvfz backup.tar.gz {} \;
```

This will look for all directories (`-type d`) and execute a certain command on them (`tar cvfz backup.tar.gz {}`). In which `{}` is a placeholder for the directory found.

If you want to **preserve the name** of the dir, simply use `{}` a second time:

```
 find /opt/backup/ -mtime +"2" -type d -exec tar cvfz {}.tar.gz {} \;
```

Note that no quotes are required around `{}` as special chars will be handled well inside `find`'s `exec`.